# How to CSS select all cells with colspan set?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select all cells in the table header which have the `colspan` attribute set.

Of course I could do something like:

```
 table thead th[colspan="1"],
 table thead th[colspan="2"],
 table thead th[colspan="3"] {

 }
```

but I'm looking for something like this:

```
 table thead th[colspan*=""] {

 }
```

which does not seem to work.

**Question**:
How to select all cells with colspan set in a table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use

```
table thead th[colspan]
```

According to the [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors),

> **`[att]`**
>
> Match when the element sets the "att" attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.

Comment: It should be "thead th[colspan]". "Table" is redundant as these elements cannot exist outside of a table (but th can be used outside of thead).

Comment: @tomasz86 Nitpicking, `thead` can exist outside of a `table`. It would be invalid HTML, but possible: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/10az5bet/)

Comment: I don't think there is any point in discussing invalid HTML... In a normal situation "table thead" is redundant (same as "ul li", "dl dt", etc.). Overspecifying will just make the CSS bloated and is bad in terms of performance (one more thing to check, unnecessarily).